# AWS Lambda: Synchronous invocation flow

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have 2 AWS Lambda functions and I'm trying to call one synchronously from the other by specifying the `InvocationType: 'RequestResponse'`. The Docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-sync.html) state that the calling function would wait for a response or timeout. By this I thought that the caller function would pause in the given location until one of the above 2 occur, however the results I see are not in line with this.

Here is a high level overview of what I'm doing:

Caller function (Lambda 1)

```
      var requestPayload = {'url':url};
      var params = {
        FunctionName:Lambda2Name,
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        LogType: 'Tail',
        Payload: JSON.stringify(requestPayload)
      };
      lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) 
          console.log("Error");
        else {
            console.log("THE response is: ",data.Payload)
        }
      });
      for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        console.log("Sample ",i);
      }
```

Calling function (Lambda2)

This just queries the URL that is passed to it and returns the result. However in the result I don't see a single response, and I see `Sample` printed 10 times to the console. Neither do I see an error nor do I see the data payload. So my doubt is which part of the execution is synchronous, I believe there is a mistake in my understanding. Appreciate if someone could clarify what I'm missing.

UPD: Lambda 2

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      const vendorUrl = "xxxx";
  
      http.get(vendorUrl, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
          context.succeed(JSON.parse(data));
        });
      }).on("error", (err) => {
        context.succeed(null);
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
      });
};
```

Comment: You forgot to add the lamda2 function ;-). lambda.invoke sends a request to the service and then, without waiting for the response, continous with the for loop. You passed a callback to the invoke function with the second argument. When the service is ready it sends an response. The client lib then calls the given callback with a `data` and an optional `err` variable. At this time the for loop has already completed. If I understood correctly, none of the two prints in the callback were shown. That's a bit strange. It means that the client gets no response and also no timeout occurs.

Comment: Ahh, I forgot, Perhaps the Lambda function has already completed, then the callback woukld never be called and hence no output is shown.

Comment: And one more thought: AWS Lambda function should only run a short time and should have no side effects (pure function). That means they get input, do their work and return output. But inside they should not other lambda function or manipulate a state. That also means the synchronizing them with other (long running) functions is a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected this.. but then what is the synchronous part out here. The docs also state that function waits for the response, but I don't see any waiting out here!

Comment: You used a so called reactive JavaScript function. The synchronization happens in the callback.  This function is not meant to be called from another AWS Lambda function, but from e.g. nodejs program. This type of synchronization is very common in JavaScript and replaces thread handling which was long time not possible in JavaScript. You could implement the data handling code in the callback. But you also must ensure that the AWS Lambda function wait until the callback is ready. That is really complicated, perhaps you can put the lambda in an endless sleep and wake it up when the cb is ready.

Comment: Perhaps the library you use (where the lambda.invoke function is defined) allows to use the method in a synchronous way. But I don't know the lib, so I can't say how. Perhaps if you omit the callback function.

Comment: I'm still not clear by what you mean by ***synchronisation happens in the callback*** could you explain what would the difference be if I used ```InvocationType: 'Event'``` which means asynchronous processing instead of ```InvocationType: 'RequestResponse'``` which has been used above

Comment: A reactive JavaScript function call is asynchrounos by itselves. It doesn't matter if the systemcall that is performed in the background (the invokation of a lambda function) is synchronous or not.  It is a JavaScript thing, not a AWS lambda thing. You can change this behavior if you find a way to call the (JavaScript) invokation function in a synchronous mode. Is there e.g. a invokeSync function? I would expect that internally the invoke function can decide wether to run sync or async by knowing the InvocationTpye. But, you observed smth. different.

Comment: Ok I get what you said, I tried to make the program sleep for a couple of seconds by  doing this 
`
    const sleep = (delay) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));   
    await sleep(5000);
`
and I saw that I get output on the console printed from the callback. Even if the program finishes execution won't these events (execution of callback) still be in the even loop. Any pointers regarding this strange happenning?

Comment: If the program / prcess finishes then, there is no event loop anymore ;-).

Comment: Yeah you're right but my point here being either the error / the data should've been part of the event loop. Aren't these 2 cases exhaustive?

Comment: The invoke method uses a low level function to communicate with the lambda processor. It sends a request to it and waits for the repsonse. If the response arives, it creates a callback function by wrapping your callback function and saves the response and error struct in local variables/parameters of the wrapper function. Then is adds the wrapper to the JS event queue. The event runner uses the next Tick to run the wrapper. With the variables it gets from the lambda runner. The event queue will be cleared and deleted when the process ends then all is lost. Does this answer you question?

Comment: Yes this does make sense, as if the addition of the callback to the even queue was done before then I should've seen something logged onto the console. But I was trying to contrast the situation I had with something like

`
setTimeout(console.log("HI"), 3000);
console.log("Hi THERE");
`

So in this case I do see a `HI` printed 3s after `HI THERE`, how is my situation different from this case. Really enjoyed the discussion with you! Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think, yout situation is different. The event loop does not have one event queue. NodeJs uses about six of them. Two of them, the timer queue (see setTimeout, setInterval) and the Pending Callbacks Queue (see nextTick function) are treated more special, as they prevent the event loop from being shutdown as long as the queues have more events.  It seems that the invoke function adds a non blocking io callback to the Poll Queue. It the event loop starts a new iteration, it checks if there are events in the Timer Queue or the Pending Callback Queue and stops running if there are none.

Comment: This comments are not mentioned to extend your question or for a longer discussion. I enjoy our discussion too, but we should care about the rules here.  It would be better, to edit your question, if you find out that it was not complete, Then others don't have to read the comments and are able to see what you asked at one single place. If you do, I would add an answer to summarize our conversation.  Alternativly, you can add an answer by yourself and mark it as the accepted answer.  Unanswered question produce a lot of reviews, which is not necessary ;-).